# Como redirecionar o link no web.xml do vraptor para um Controller?

Tags: java, xml, java-ee, vraptor, página-de-erro

Eu tenho os seguintes códigos abaixo:

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500</location>
</error-page>
```

ErrorController.java:

```
@Controller
@Resource
public class ErrorController {

    public ErrorController(){

    }

    @Path("/error/404")
    public void error404(){

    }

    @Path("/error/500")
    public void error500(){

    }

}
```

Gostaria de que o web.xml, quando o usuário entrar num link desconhecido ou que leve a um desses erros, fosse redirecionado ao Controller, para tratar a página dentro do Controller mesmo.

Já está criada as respectivas páginas jsp, dentro da pasta error, conforme solicitação do VRaptor, utilizando o TomCat ou o GlassFish, a página fica em branco.

Comment: Você precisa que redirecionar para cada Controller especifico? já tentou usar o result.forwardTo(); ?

Comment: Na verdade, quero que redirecione a esse controller apenas, para que nele possa tratar os error-pages.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem esse `tratar` os error pages, não seria melhor adicionar alguma mensagem na tela com um botão para redirecionar para a página anterior?

Comment: Dessa forma sua @WellingtonAvelino já estou fazendo, porém não mostra alguns componentes na página, que são carregados no servidor, através de um Intercept, então terei que passar por um controller pra que acione o intercept e eu carregue outros componentes através desse controller, e o `tratar` seria carregar esses componentes diferentes no servidor, e gravar uma auditoria, de forma diferente para cada erro, no banco de dados, por isso preciso do Controller.

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma lida na doc, porquê já faz alguns meses que parei de usar Vraptor

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha @TiagoFerezin

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino encontrei a solução e já postei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

Criei a página 404.jsp que apenas redirecionará para o Controller ficando assim:

404.jsp:

```
<body>
    <div id="errorContent"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Iniciando JQuery(document).ready");
    jQuery(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {

                        irUrl = "/site/error/404";

                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    url : irUrl,
                                    type : "POST",
                                    beforeSend : function() {



                                        contexto = "/site";

                                        $.blockUI({
                                            message : "erro 404",
                                            theme : false,
                                            baseZ : 99999
                                        });

                                    },
                                    success : function(data) {
                                        $.unblockUI();
                                        $("#errorContent").html(data);

                                    },
                                    error : function(data) {
                                        // alert('error data: ' + data);

                                        $.unblockUI();

                                        $("#errorContent").html(data);

                                    }
                                });

                    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Que irá carregar o jsp error404.jsp através do Controller pelo método de Post para o usuário não ter acesso a url:

ErrorController.java:

```
@Controller
@Resource
public class ErrorController {

    public ErrorController() {

    }

    @Post("/error/404")
    public void error404() {

    }

    @Post("/error/500")
    public void error500() {

    }

}
```

no web.xml redirecionei a esse 404.jsp:

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

e criei uma pagina jsp de erro 404(error404.jsp) personalizado e fiz ambos pra 500.